# Can't ssh to remote repository from command line

Tags: windows, git, bash, ssh, command-line

I'm trying to connect to a remote repository under a specific IP address.

I received the private key through email and I'm on windows using Putty. The .ppk file is in Pageant.

I also created a GIT_SSH environment variable.

After these steps my personal IP was then listed in the firewall, so I guess I was able to connect.

However, when I use git bash to connect to the server, I get the message "permission denied (public key)".

The commands I used are:

`$ ssh [IP]
 $ ssh [username]@IP
 $ ssh -T [username]@IP`

I looked up online exhaustively but with no success so far and I really need to access the repo as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance! 
Obrigada :)

Comment: So it works with putty but not with the ssh command-line utility? None of your ssh command examples include specifying the key. Please clarify exactly how you're telling ssh what key file to use. Try running ssh with "-vv" to print debugging output, then [edit] your question to show the exact command that you ran and the output which it produced.

Comment: @Kenster I guess so. this is my first time ever using ssh. Probably my ssh commands are wrong. how do I tell which key to use?

Comment: **-i identity_file** - in other words `ssh -i <path/to/privatekey.key> [username]@[IP]`

Comment: Thanks @Katie !
I just needed to put both path and username@IP with double quotes in order to make it work. like this ssh -i "path/to/privatekey.key" "username@IP"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to go about it

### Using Pageant directly inside Git Bash

This requires setting the GIT_SSH environment variable to the full path of plink.exe (which is part of the putty suite).

Also, I would highly recommend checking if plink.exe works inside GIT Bash as follows:

```
Full-path-to-plink.exe -v -P port sshusername@sshserver
```

Another thing to check is the version of Putty suite that you are using. ( I can dig out the details later but) version 0.60 had a bug due to which processes inside cmd could not access Pageant.  I believe the issue was fixed in v 0.62 but feel free to use the latest (v 0.67)

---

### Convert putty key to OpenSSH format

Another possibility is exporting the putty key to the OpenSSH format by using puttygen.exe and the using the exported key directly inside GIT Bash:

1. Open PuttyGen
2. Click Load
3. Load your private key
4. Go to `Conversions->Export OpenSSH` and export your private key
5. Copy your private key to `~/.ssh/id_dsa` (or `id_rsa`).
6. Create the RFC 4716 version of the public key using `ssh-keygen`

   ```
   ssh-keygen -e -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa > ~/.ssh/id_dsa_com.pub
   ```
7. Convert the RFC 4716 version of the public key to the OpenSSH format:

   ```
   ssh-keygen -i -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa_com.pub > ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub
   ```

Then you can do something like this in GIT Bash to test the ssh connectivity:

```
GIT_SSH=ssh
ssh -v sshusername@sshserver -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: @LunaPaglarelli no worries :) ... What solved the problem for you ?

Comment: I used the Pageant option you sent, thanks so much, @AshutoshJindal! But I still cant access the repo, unfortunnately. It says I need to install some packages. "57 packages needed for security out of 149 available. Run "sudo yum update" to apply all updates fatal: interactive git shell is not enabled. hint: ~/git-shell-commands should exist and have read and execute access. connection to [ip] closed." Im trying to find a solution since yesterday. In case that wont take much of your time, do you know where I can find this? Obrigada!